# Combobox: Sort options by usage

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox

***Starting Point:***
I have a datagridview with a combobox. The combobox has about 30 options (growing) and every user uses the options with a different frequency.

***Question:***
I am looking for a way to sort the options in that combobox by usage for every client.

***What I tried:***
I tried to use a counter and store that value in an external .txt file and open that again when the user opens his client again. Is there another way since this is a bad solution.

***Additional Information:***
I update the clients with ClickOnce.

Comment: It's better to have a Table on your database with the usage information, isn't it?

Comment: As suggested by the previous comment: relying on a DB is an efficient and convenient way to account for most of data-storage-related issues. Temporary files are usually a less recommendable solution (although might be the best option for small implementations where no DB is present). All this by assuming that you want to keep the values after the program has been closed; otherwise (if you need to access these value only when the program is running), it would be better to rely on memory (e.g., arrays).

Comment: user level data such as thus could also be stored using a Class (and/or List or Dictionary) of the options/copunt between runs by serializing them.  .NET comes with an XML and Binary serializer which are not too difficult to use.  If there is not already a db in the app (and sometimes even if there is) it is a good way to store volatile user data or preferences.  (your question seems to have little to do with your title though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make each item you add to the combobox a custom class that includes a count property, overriding the ToString method will allow the objects to be added directly to the combobox.  Using a list to keep track of the sorting works well with the AddRange method of the combobox.items collection.

```
Public Class CBItem
    Public Item As String = ""
    Public Count As Integer = 0
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Item
    End Function
End Class

    Dim CBItems As New List(Of CBItem)
    'This adds items to the list for demonstration purposes
    For i = 1 To 5
        CBItems.Add(New CBItem With {.Item = i.ToString, .Count = 5 - i})
    Next
    CBItems = CBItems.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Count).ToList
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(CBItems.ToArray)
```

The [`My.Settings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/saa62613%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would probably be handy for storing the list between uses.